# How to show `*Completions*` buffer if input is successfully completed?

Tags: completion

I imagine this is a simple question, but I have been unable to find an answer.

`C-x C-f`, as you know, brings up a find file minibuffer. Entering a few characters afterward and pressing `TAB` will autocomplete if there is only one valid option, or bring up a window with multiple options otherwise. I wanted to use `TAB` to cycle through valid options, and setting `completion-cycle-threshold` to, say, `5` lets me do that when there are 5 or fewer valid options. As matters currently stand, these are treated as successful completions and the `*Completions*` buffer does not show up. However, I would like to view the `*Completions*` buffer even when I am cycling through valid options.

**Is there a way to invoke *Completions* when I am cycling through successful `TAB` autocompletes?** Ideally, this would exclude the case where there is *only one* successful completion (`[Sole completion]` in the minibuffer), but that is not mandatory.